# Permissions for reading a directory in android

Tags: android

I am unable to read the data stored in the external storage directory even after giving the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in `manifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In the android device monitor of my emulator, I can see that my storage directory doesn't have all the required permissions. The link is below.

[android device monitor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUeFD.png)

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? What is your `targetSdkVersion` (e.g., in your `app/build.gradle` file)? Is that `<uses-permission>` element in the proper place in the manifest? See: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. My target sdk version was 23 and I changed it to 22 and it worked.